# Pdf error after download as Content-Disposition' = attachment

Tags: django, pdf, content-type

In my rest framework, I have a retrieve method on ModelViewSet as

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        print(serializer.data)
        pdf = serializer.data['pdf']
        response = Response(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="invoice.pdf"'
        return response
```

pdf is the model field of the FileField type.

I am able to automatically download the pdf file on URL but when I try to open the pdf it gives an error,
on chrome is says "Failed to load PDF document" and on pdf viewer is says "not a supported file type or the file has been damaged, (send as an email attachment and not correctly decoded)"

What more I need to do to make it work correctly.

While the pdf is of the correct format and can be opened directly,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as pdf was only URL it was not valid.

rewriting response as :

`response = HttpResponse(instance.pdf, content_type='application/pdf')`

solved the issue.